# javascript to asp.net ClientIDMode

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm new and learning asp.net and javascript.

It could be silly question, because I would like to check how to work on asp.net with javascript.

The button calls OnClientClick for client side only and I want that the javascipt changes the label on asp.net. 
When it press the button, it seems be changed, but it will turn back to original label.

Is there way to make static the label value from javascript?

Thanks in advance.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function calledFn()
{
document.getElementById('<%=Label1.ClientID%>').innerHTML = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').value;
document.getElementById('<%=Label2.ClientID%>').innerHTML = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>').value;
document.getElementById('<%=Label3.ClientID%>').innerHTML = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox3.ClientID%>').value;
document.getElementById('<%=Label4.ClientID%>').innerHTML = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox4.ClientID%>').value;
} 
</script>
```

```html
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br /><br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Run JavaScript Code" OnClientClick="calledFn()"/> 
<br /><br />

<asp:Label ClientIDMode="Static" ID="Label1" runat="server">t111</asp:Label> 
<asp:Label ClientIDMode="Static" ID="Label2" runat="server">t222</asp:Label> 
<asp:Label ClientIDMode="Static" ID="Label3" runat="server">t333</asp:Label> 
<asp:Label ClientIDMode="Static" ID="Label4" runat="server">t444</asp:Label> 

</form>
</body>
```

Comment: `tom tom` have you looked at this site [MSDN Control.ClientIdMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @DJKRAZE - I bet he wants the client-side label text chamge to stick through postback.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I'm not well asp.net and javascipt either. but if I want to like this way, is there alternative way to pass from javascript to asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript changes will not be saved.

You have to use session,view state, or hidden fields to temporarily store changes then rebind them on pageload